# Membres de l'Académie française — Members of l'Académie française

Tags: discussion

Des membres de l’Académie française se sont-ils inscrits sur ce site?

---

Are there any members of *l'Académie française* registered on the site?

Comment: On peut rêver, mais j'ai comme un doute. Le fait que je les imagine comme de vieux croutons incapables de sortir leurs nez de leurs dictionnaires n'aide pas.

Comment: @Joubarc Même si beaucoup le pensent, le faire remarquer n'aide pas.

Answer (score 4):

Donnons une réponse factuelle à cette question factuelle : si d’aucuns l’ont fait, ils n’ont pas révélé leur qualité.

---

Let's give a factual answer to a factual question: if any of them have registered, they haven't revealed the fact.

Comment: Justement, il fallait voir là une invitation à le faire.